# Bound Button.IsEnabled() Property doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, button, binding

I'm new with MVVM Pattern.

I was wondering why everytime my `TextChanged()` event is fired, the binded `IsEnabled()` property doesn't change its state. The `TextChanged()` event is calling `IsValid()` to check for data validation.

I have this simple `ViewModel` class

```
public class myViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public bool IsOk { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand OnValidateExecute { get; set; }

    public myViewModel()
    {
        OnValidateExecute = new RelayCommand(p => IsValid(), p => true);
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        // other codes
        IsOk = MethodName();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsOk");
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on `IsValid()` and the code is working fine. I was wondering why `IsEnabled` property is not working as expected.

This is my `XAML` code

```
<TextBox ...other propeties here....>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnValidateExecute}">
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>

<Button x:Name="btnSave" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOk, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            ...other propeties here....>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSaveExecute}">
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

What I want is that when `IsOk` property is false, the button should be `Disabled`, otherwise, `Enabled`.

Is there some wrong with my data binding? If this question has been asked before, kindly help me redirect on to it.

**UPDATE 1**

Another problem I have encounter with this code is that, the `IsValid()` function is triggered first before the setting of value on the textbox. Here's an example, Assuming that the starting value of the textbox is `0`, when I changed it to, let's say, 9, the value that will be check is the previous value `0` instead of `9`. Any idea why this is happening? Is there a problem with the binding?

Comment: 'IsEnabled' property not working as expected - What you really expect on that property? Should the button be disabled on empty text?

Comment: @XAMLLover yes. I tried to debug the code and `IsOK` property value is changing but the button is not affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer, and include my MVVM Framework's important part. Beside this I put some extra function on it . I can't put here all of my library. But I'm sure it will help.

If you use Commanding you should be aware of `CanExecuteChanged` in `ICommand` interface. You should trigger this command when a property changed. (I don't use RelayCommand, it is 3.party .)

`Use my DCommand :) this is the most important part`

It has easy implementation ,
and has `FirePropertyChanged` method. This method fires `CanExecuteChanged` of ICommand if it is not null.

An example Command

Anonymous syntax

```
   DCommand commandPost=new DCommand(()=>{
      //TODO:Command's real execute method Post()
        },
      ()=>
      {
         return this.TextBoxBoundProperty.IsValid;
      }
    )
```

Non-anonymous syntax

```
    DCommand commandPost=(Post,Validate);
```

beside this you should trigger canexecutechanged by following method in your viewModel's ctor.

```
    this.PropertyChanged += (sender, prop) =>
          {
        //I preffered canExcuteChange for any property changes for my viewmodel class. You could put your own logic. if(prop.PropertyName.equals("thisone"));
        //Just works for this class's property changed
                this.InvokeOnClassPropertyChange(prop.PropertyName, () =>
                {
                    this.commandPost.FirePropertyChanged();
                });
          }
```

InvokeOnClassPropertyChange works when if the property is ViewModel class's property.

```
    public static void InvokeOnClassPropertyChange(this object instance,string PropertyName,Action action)
    {
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        var fulllist = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(w => w.DeclaringType == type).ToList();
        if (fulllist.Select(p => p.Name).Contains(PropertyName))
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

The above code shows `InvokeOnClassPropertyChange` extension method. 
The below one shows my `DCommand` implements ICommand.

```
   public class DCommand :ICommand
    {
    public void FirePropertyChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged!=null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);            
    }

    Func<bool> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }
    Action<object> Action { get; set; }


    public DCommand(Action<object> executeMethod)
    {
        this.Action = executeMethod;            
    }

    public DCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        this.Action = new Action<object>(
            (prm) =>
            {
                executeMethod.Invoke();
            }
            );
    }

    public DCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        : this(executeMethod)
    {            
        this.CanExecuteFunc = canExecuteMethod;            
    }

    public DCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        : this(executeMethod)
    {
        this.CanExecuteFunc = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter=null)
    {
        if (CanExecuteFunc == null)
            return true;

        return CanExecuteFunc.Invoke();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter=null)
    {

        if (CanExecuteFunc == null || CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            Action.Invoke(parameter);                
        }

    }
}
```

After all,
If you want to change your ViewModel property when textbox's text changes immediately you should bind by this way.

`Text="{Binding BoundProperty,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Yeah it really steal time from work (: I've been using this for two years. I was waiting for a good question to share.

Comment: Note that `RelayCommand` support `CanExecute` like `DCommand` in @DavutGürbüz answer. The `FirePropertyChanged` is named `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="100">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnValidateExecute, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=TextBox1}" />
               </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Width="120" Height="25" Content="click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOk}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSaveExecute}">
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
               </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Only add a command parameter.

```
public class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsOk { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand OnValidateExecute { get; set; }

    public myViewModel()
    {
        OnValidateExecute = new RelayCommand(p => 
            {
                Message = p as string;
                IsValid();
            }, p => true);
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        bool valid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);
        IsOk = valid;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsOk"));
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

It works well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad. It's a typo. All of my Property should be `IsOk`.

Comment: It works fine here. Just the TextChanged not reflected on the text property. Or you can post the complete code.

Comment: Why use interaction triggers on the text box text instead of a direct two-way binding?

Comment: If use two way binding, it will trigger after the textbox lost focus.

Comment: Thats why you have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: Yes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is better. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Davut Gürbüz answer :

On `Button` you have a [Command property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), use this property is better than `i:Interaction.Triggers` (easyer to read).

Like Davut Gürbüz say [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand.aspx) have a [CanExecuteFunc parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh727783.aspx). If you use this property, the state of your button changes automatically.

**Xaml code :**

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding BoundProperty,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ...other propeties here.... />
<Button
    x:Name="btnSave"
    Command="{Binding OnSaveExecute}"
    ...other propeties here.... />
```

**C#**

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the OnSaveExecute.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand OnSaveExecute
{
    get
    {
        return _onSaveExecute 
            ?? (_onSaveExecute = new RelayCommand(
                                    () =>
                                    {
                                              // Save action or call save method
                                    },
                                    () => IsOk));
    }
}
private RelayCommand _onSaveExecute;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the IsOk property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event.
/// </summary>
public bool IsOk
{
    get { return _isOk; }
    set
    {
        if (_isOk == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _isOk = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsOk");
        OnSaveExecute.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
private bool _isOk = false;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the BoundProerty property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event.
/// </summary>
public string BoundProerty
{
    get { return _boundProerty; }
    set
    {
        if (_boundProerty == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _boundProerty = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("BoundProerty");
        IsValid();
    }
}
private string _boundProerty = false;

public myViewModel()
{
}

public bool IsValid()
{
    // other codes
    IsOk = MethodName();
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing about RelayCommand  In fact we can remove EventTriggers as I shared on end of my post `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` support reflecting immediate changes on BoundProerty. When the property changes FirePropertyChanged  executes. So we don't need actually any TextChaged event trigger.

Comment: Ok, i just edit my post to add `BoundProerty`... Thx ! Feel free to edit the answer if you want to add elements ;)